# SQL Server stored procedure returns different with query result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL Server. I wrote a simple stored procedure that returns rows with data condition.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test.newArtists
    @LastUpdated smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM ARTIST
    WHERE GENERATED > @LastUpdated OR MODIFIED > @LastUpdated;
END
```

When I execute this stored procedure, it returns 0 rows. like ...

```
DECLARE  @temp DATETIME;
SET @temp = CONVERT (DATETIME, '2016/12/05');

EXEC test.newArtists @LastUpdated = @temp;
```

However, when I execute the query without using procedure, it returns about 5,000 rows.

```
DECLARE  @temp DATETIME;
SET @temp = CONVERT (DATETIME, '2016/12/05');

SELECT *
FROM ARTIST
WHERE GENERATED > @temp OR MODIFIED > @temp;
```

I just do not understand whey those two returns different results.

Thanks for explanations!

===================================================

I find the problem. Thanks.

I'am using `test` schema.
So I connected to `test`. However, When I use `SELECT * FROM ARTIST` it does not search `test.ARTIST`, but `ARTIST` table which belongs to `dbo`.

Summary.

- The basic problem here is I got 2 tables with name `ARTIST`.
- However, I still do not understand why it automatically look for `dbo` schema.

I got little experience with `MYSQL`, but when I connect to a certain schema, it only find objects inside of the schema. Is it normal or should I do some work to set prefix?

Thanks for answers though b

Comment: The only obvious difference is the (seemingly a bit arbitrary) use of smalldatetime as the input parameter to the procedure. Any particular reason you chose this over datetime  / datetime2? The MS Docs advise not to use it any more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql . Not sure exactly what difference it would make in your case, but presumably some, as that's the only observable difference in your code.

Comment: Try to pass the data without converting it: DECLARE  @temp DATETIME = '20161205'

Comment: What are types of the fields GENERATED and MODIFIED?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Sql Server 2016

Comment: @DenisRubashkin They are `smalldatetime`.

Comment: @sepupic It works either `datatime` / `smalldatetime`. it just my mistake to not note which schema to use. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for advice to deprecated data type. I used it since somebody already uses that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is always good practice to refer to database objects by a schema
>   name and the object name, separated by a period (.).

---

> object referred to without an explicit schema name ... will be located by searching the default schema first, followed by the dbo schema

---

Source: [SQL Server Best Practices – Implementation of Database Object Schemas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Dbo is the default schema, it will always go to that one first if the schema is not specified. It is a good practice to always specify the schema in the query especially if you are using more than one. That way it won't waste time looking in the wrong schema first.

Comment: No it won't. References to objects that are not schema qualified will be resolved first in the user's default schema. If not found there, THEN the engine will use dbo.

Comment: @SMor I assume you are probably right. But in my case, I connected with test schema and it searches from `dbo`. Is there any way to find what is user's default schema? - I thought it is what mentioned in the url. like `jdbc:sqlserver://{{url}}:{{port}};databaseName=test`.